# Keras and tensorflow eager execution

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a model from https://github.com/bonlime/keras-deeplab-v3-plus that I try to customize a bit.

I want to run it with Tensorflow Eager mode

```
from model import Deeplabv3
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()

model = Deeplabv3(weights='pascal_voc', input_shape=(200,200,3), backbone='mobilenetv2', classes=64)
batch = tf.zeros((1,200,200,3))
f = model(batch)
```

However this gives the error:

> model.py", line 236, in _inverted_res_block
>       in_channels = inputs._keras_shape[-1] AttributeError: 'DeferredTensor' object has no attribute '_keras_shape'

It is about this part of the code

```
def _inverted_res_block(inputs, expansion, stride, alpha, filters, block_id, skip_connection, rate=1):
    in_channels = inputs._keras_shape[-1]
    #in_channels = inputs.get_shape()[-1].value
    #in_channels = tf.shape(inputs)[-1]

    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()

    pointwise_conv_filters = int(filters * alpha)
    pointwise_filters = _make_divisible(pointwise_conv_filters, 8)
    x = inputs

    prefix = 'expanded_conv_{}_'.format(block_id)
    if block_id:
        # Expand

        x = Conv2D(expansion * in_channels, kernel_size=1, padding='same',
                   use_bias=False, activation=None,
                   name=prefix + 'expand')(x)
```

How to solve this?

Comment: While eager execution is compatible (and recommended to be used) with `tf.keras`, I don't think this extends to the `keras` module.

Answer (score 1):

As [P-gn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1735003/p-gn) pointed out:

- `tf.keras` (included with TensorFlow) supports eager execution, the `keras` module does not.
- `tf.keras` implements the `keras` API spec, so it should be a drop-in replacement for any program using `keras` (e.g., change references to `keras.Model` to `tf.keras.Model`). Plus it additionally supports eager execution in TensorFlow.

Answer (score 0):

I have made this change:

**Instead this line:** in_channels = inputs.shape[-1].value
**or this other line:**  inputs._keras_shape[-1]

***I have used this other:*** in_channels = inputs.shape.as_list()[-1]

and it works for me.